# Why do I get java.lang.NullPointerException at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method) when calling JasperFillManager?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jasper-reports

JasperFillManager is throwing a null pointer exception when I pass sql connection in its parameter but it runs fine when I pass JRResultSetDatasource.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2036)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:609)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when I pass connection in fillReport it gives exception.

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, reportConnection);
```

I am also using a subreport so that is why I am not using JRResultSetDatasource and using connection. I am just stuck into this note that when I pass JRResultSetDatasource it works fine and when I also pass connection object in a HasMap parameter it gives same error as above.

Answer (score 9):

I just fixed this two minutes ago updating my iReport jar file to the last version

Answer (score 4):

Your jasper-designer and jar in your project should be the same version.

Answer (score 2):

The Jar files in the projects lib folder should be matching the version of iReport
 I had the same problem and it has been solved by using correct jar files.
 you can take a look at the link below:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/

Answer (score 1):

There is no an issue to replace from old .jar to new .jar. If you have an option. Suppose you need to maintain the old jar but it should work means. Please use this.

The following code works in higher version [Ex: 4.1.1] not in older version [Ex: 3.7.6].

```
 <subreport>
       <reportElement positionType="Float" x="335" y="25" width="175"
                height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"
                backcolor="#99ccff"/>

                <dataSourceExpression>
                new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
                ($F{subReportBeanList})
                </dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String">
                   <![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subReport.jasper"]]>
                </subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
```

The same code works in older version with little bit modification.

```
<parameter name="subreportParameter" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <subreport>
       <reportElement  positionType="Float" x="1" y="2" width="532" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#99CCFF"/>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
                ($F{subReportBeanList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA[$P{subreportParameter}]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
```